# Initial scroll position of overflow:auto in IE

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a scrollable div with lots of content inside:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;height: 500px;"
[lots of content]
</div>
```

In IE, the initial position of the scrollbar is not at the top, but in the middle, so it does not show the beginning of the text. Chrome doesn't do this. How can I fix that?

Comment: On which version of IE are you testing?

Comment: I tested with IE10 and IE11.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle?

Comment: Try to add: position:relative; display:block on your div

Comment: Its used in a YUI2 SimpleDialog element, so its not easy to setup a fiddle. So its not supposed to do that? Also, position:relative; display:block didn't help.

Comment: I've solved this meanwhile by doing a el.scrollIntoView(), executed in an onDomReady event handler.